# Difficulty displaying string in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a simple rails app to read from a text file and display the information on a webpage.  the html code is this

```
 <td><%= application.server %></td>
```

I am using mysql2 and the column server is a text type. (not string)
when I check the database the data in it is of the form "apachetra-137.vm.micronet.net"
but on the HTML page, i only get the "micronet" string!!  Why does it return me only a part of the string but not all of it since in the database it is stored as whole??

Comment: You mean `application.server` is returning part of the string?

Comment: hey I had to restart the server! weird! I changes from sqlite to mysql but it didnt work, so I had to restart the server

Comment: ha ha ha... 
new thing to learn :) Anyway, great that the problem fixed :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as no-longer-active because according to comments author has solved his issue, but question still appears in search in spite of it won't receive author's attention anymore.